# WCF Application hosted service Faulted State exception?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, console-application

No idea what's going on.  Simple application hosted service.  Ran fine on server A.  Copied everything over to server B...and suddenly won't launch.

Any tips?  Ideas?  I'll happily provide more info.  Thanks for any help.

Error message:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost, cannot be
>   used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Code (FAILS AT HOST.OPEN()_

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/Brp");
                Uri mexUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/Brp/mex");

                // Create the ServiceHost.
                using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BBService), baseAddress))
                {

                    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                    smb.HttpGetUrl = mexUri;
                    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

                    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                    host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

                    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

                    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IBService), binding, "");
                    // Enable metadata publishing.

                    var behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
                    behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

                    host.Open();

                    Console.ReadLine();


                    // Close the ServiceHost.
                    host.Close();
                }
            } catch (Exception excep)
            {
                writeMessage("EXCEPTION!!! - " + excep.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs into this do: `Right-click -> Run as administrator`

Comment: I thought it's obvious from the right-on-the-money error message you got :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow certain rules while working with Message contract
    1. When using Message contract type as parameter, Only one parameter can be used in servicie Operation
[OperationContract]
void SaveEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails emp);

```
2. Service operation either should return Messagecontract type or it should not return any value
```

[OperationContract]
EmployeeDetails GetEmployeeDetails();

```
3. Service operation will accept and return only message contract type. Other data types are not allowed.
```

[OperationContract]
EmployeeDetails ModifyEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails emp);

Note: If a type has both Message and Data contract, service operation will accept only message contract.